# Can not connect ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I want to connect my PLSQL developer tools into database but fail to connect due to error below.
ORA-12514: TNS: listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Check configuration below. How to configure to make it works?

```
SQL> select value from v$parameter where name='service_names';
VALUE
orcl

SQL> select instance from v$thread;
INSTANCE
orcl
SQL> select host_name,instance_name,version from v$instance;
HOST_NAME
INSTANCE_NAME    VERSION
ex-cs-b
orcl             11.2.0.1.0

SQL> select global_name from global_name;

GLOBAL_NAME
ORCL
SQL>

lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 23-OCT-2017 16:49:51

Copyright (c) 1991, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                23-OCT-2017 16:49:40
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 10 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/ex-cs-b/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=ex-cs-b)(PORT=1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully

lsnrctl services

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 23-OCT-2017 16:58:18

Copyright (c) 1991, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully



more tnsnames.ora
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: /app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network
/admin/tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ex-cs-b)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )

more listener.ora
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: /app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network
/admin/listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ex-cs-b)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
ADR_BASE_LISTENER = /app/oracle
```

Comment: more sqlnet.ora
# sqlnet.ora Network Configuration File: /app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/net
work/admin/sqlnet.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
ADR_BASE = /app/oracle

Answer (score 1):

Your database hasn't been registered with the listener. [`lsnrctl status`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14213/lsnrctl.htm) returned "The listener supports no services" and your [listener.ora](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28316/listenercfg.htm#i486171) file doesn't have a SID_LIST.

Connect to your database instance as a SYSDBA and run:

```
 ALTER SYSTEM SET LOCAL_LISTENER='';
```

If that doesn't resolve your problem then you mostly likely have several listeners and you'll need to follow [the registration process](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28316/listenercfg.htm#NETAG299) for the listener that you want.

All of this complexity is to allow an operating system to run multiple listeners, which can be useful.

Do note that depending on how you started your instance, you may need to specify [`SCOPE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_2013.htm#i2282157) on the `ALTER SYSTEM` command or your configuration will disappear on restart of the instance.

Comment: I have try to add the SID list in the listener.ora. But found error below.  more listener.ora
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: /app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network
/admin/listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ex-cs-b)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

Comment: SID_LIST_LISTENER=
  (SID_LIST=
    (SID_DESC=
       (GLOBAL_DBNAME=ORCL)
       (ORACLE_HOME=/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1)
       (SID_NAME=orcl))
    (SID_DESC=
        (SID_NAME=orcl)
        (ORACLE_HOME=/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1)
        (PROGRAM=EXTPROC1521)))

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = /app/oracle

Comment: lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 23-OCT-2017 16:47:49

Copyright (c) 1991, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   Linux Error: 2: No such file or directory
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ex-cs-b)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   Linux Error: 111: Connection refused

Comment: Was the listener running when you ran the commands in these comments? Try `lsnrctl start` as described in [this Oracle community thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2188674?tstart=0)