# Unabe to resolve cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, cx-oracle

I am trying to access an oracle database on another machine. I am using:

- Ubuntu Server 18.04
- oracle client 12.2
- python 3.6 and cx_oracle 6.4.1

I constanly get this error:

#### Error

```
File "basic_test.py", line 5, in <module>
    con =  cx_Oracle.connect('jalabe','jalabepass', cx_Oracle.makedsn('ipserver','port',None,'prod'))
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

#### basic_tst.py

```
import cx_Oracle
# first attempt
# con =  cx_Oracle.connect('jalabe/jalabepass@ipaddress/prod')

# second attempt 
con =  cx_Oracle.connect('jalabe','jalabepass', cx_Oracle.makedsn('ipaddress','port',None,'prod'))
print(con.version)
con.close()
```

#### tnsnames.ora

```
DATABASE.WORLD =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ipaddress)(PORT = port))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = prod)
    )
  )
```

#### Other info

- `$ORACLE_HOME` as `/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/`
- File `tnsnames.ora` is inside `/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/network/admin`

I have read many post without any luck. From all of the post I have read these are the ones I think are more usefull although they haven't work

- [ORA-12514 TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786782/ora-12514-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-service-requested-in-connect-d)
- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46914943/can-not-connect-ora-12514-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-service-reque](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/122800/lsnrctl-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-14-04)

I am sure it might be some character somewhere.

I don't have sqlplus installed nor tnslistener. (Could it be the cause?) (I have read that  `tnslistener` should be in the oracle server which is why i haven't installed it)

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few comments and suggestions to help you correct your issue:

1) Install SQL*Plus and use it to connect to your database. You should be able to connect using the connect string 'jalabe/jalabepass@host/service_name' where 'host' is the host on which the database is found and 'service_name' is the service name of the database you want to connect to. This same connect string should work within cx_Oracle as well. You don't need to use makedsn() or tnsnames.ora (although they should also work, of course!)

2) Do not set the environment variable ORACLE_HOME when using the Instant Client.

3) On the database machine you should be able to run the command 'lsnrctl status' which will show you the status of the listener and which services it knows about. If your service isn't in the list, that's the source of the issue!

4) If you stop and restart the listener it can take a bit of time before the database will register itself with the listener. You can force that to happen more quickly by issuing the command 'alter system register' as SYSDBA in the database (or stopping/starting the database).

Hopefully that helps you out!

Comment: Why should I not set the environment variable ORACLE_HOME? I'm trying to unset it and see if it's working. Should I declare the TNS_ADMIN variable ?

Comment: ORACLE_HOME is not used for instant client and may cause issues. TNS_ADMIN can be set if desired and must be set if your configuration files are not found in the default location.